# Web domain verification for SSL certificate

Tags: domains, web-hosting, security-certificate, dns-servers

I set up a 'Google app for work' account and in that process brought a domain name 'ahkhan.name' from eNom Inc. After that, i bought a website builder account from goDaddy, and now I want to install an SSL certificate, but this requires me to validate my domain name, by either uploading an HTML file or updating DNS record. Under goDaddy website builder account, HTML file option can't be used, so I am left with the only option to update DNS record. But I am not able to find these setting at my nameserver host website i.e. eNom's website. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Btw I also have a separate hosting account at goDaddy, so I thought that I will first point my domain to Hosting account and use HTML file to verify my domain ownership and then again point my domain name to goDaddy website builder account. But I am afraid in that case my SSL certificate may become invalid. Is SSL certificate associated with a domain name or website host?

I am very begineer in this field so kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the fastest way to do this is to have an email alias for admin@ the domain in question. DNS record verification is slow and HTML file-based verification requires you set up hosting in advance, so I always go with the email option. The issuer will email you a link to click on and you have your certificate a few minutes later, it's great.

You mention you are using Google Apps so check their [help page for email aliases here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33327?hl=en), but the answer is the same for everyone really. Just use aliases for common addresses like admin@, abuse@, etc... . This makes sure you see important notifications at the same time your hosting company does too (always a good idea).

And to answer your second question, the SSL certificate is associated with the domain name only, the Certificate Signing Request that you submitted in order to get the certificate issued has your domain(s) hard-coded into it - that's how they work.